# How to save the output of this awk command to file?

Tags: linux, awk, output

I wanna save this command to another text:
 awk '{print $2}' 
it extract's from text.
now i wanna save output too another text.
thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
awk '{ print $2 }' text.txt > outputfile.txt
```

`>` => This will redirect `STDOUT` to a file. If file not exists, it will create it. If file exists it will clear out (in effect) the content and will write new data to it

`>>` => This means same as above but if file exists, this will append new data to it.

***Eg:***

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $1 }' | tail -10 > output.txt
$ cat output.txt 
_warmd
_dovenull
_netstatistics
_avbdeviced
_krb_krbtgt
_krb_kadmin
_krb_changepw
_krb_kerberos
_krb_anonymous
_assetcache
```

Alternatively you can use the command `tee` for redirection. The command `tee` will redirect `STDOUT` to a specified file as well as the terminal screen

***For more about shell redirection goto following link:***

http://www.techtrunch.com/scripting/redirections-and-file-descriptors

Comment: Perhaps you should make it explicit that redirection is a feature of the shell, not `awk`, and isn't restricted to the latter.

Comment: Make sure to backup files before the awk operation. The `>` destroyed all my files... noooooo.

Comment: @DavidAnderton, you shouldn't be writing to same file as reading with AWK.

Comment: is it safe to write to the same file?

Comment: what if i don't want .txt but .boto?

Answer (score 31):

There is a way to do this from within awk itself ([docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html))

```
➜ cat text.txt
line 1
line 2
line three
line 4 4 4

➜ awk '{print $2}' text.txt
1
2
three
4

➜ awk '{print $2 >"text.out"}' text.txt

➜ cat text.out
1
2
three
4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command.

```
cat ORGFILENAME.TXT | awk '{print $2}' > SAVENAME.TXT
```

thx.

Comment: You do not need `cat` for that, `awk` knows how to read from files...