# Printing the output of a awk line to a file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have written a awk command to get the time stamps of specific tweets, but I am stumped on how to put in it in a file, so that I can use the data to plot graphs in R.
Here is the code I have used:

```
grep "Obama" Twitter_Data_1 | awk '{print $3, $4,$5, $6, $7}'
```

Which gives me the output:

> Tue Feb 18 23:12:59 +0000
>   Tue Feb 19 23:11:59 +0000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save the output of this awk command to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660079/how-to-save-the-output-of-this-awk-command-to-file)

Comment: Already answered thanks

Comment: Please accept the duplicate status by clicking [*That solved my problem!*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930)

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirection operator to redirect output of awk to a file directly.

Example:
`grep "Obama" Twitter_Data_1 | awk '{print $3, $4,$5, $6, $7}' > data.out`

Comment: No need repeating an evident thing, and re-answering a millionth dupe.

Comment: Hello Wikitor, I am new to Ubuntu and how it works. So probably go a bit easy, you can help or choose to ignore, rather than downvoting. Thanks anyways.