# multiple output from single input based on specific column in awk

Tags: awk

I've shoved some of it, here is `input.txt`

```
tree one
  output A.txt
  column 2 8642
  column 3
    209.98085 1513.7103
    322.45114 1574.7799
    505.41974 1656.3765
    722.01666 1819.0581
    920.3196 1994.1241
    1192.6161 2156.9763
    1497.4697 2201.7605
    2213.728 2238.4023
    3052.3992 2375.7083
    3618.3948 2490.941
    4548.857 2630.617
    5676.56 2983.299
    7460.303 3430.2625
    12284.128 4114.6753
tree one
  output B.txt
  column 2 11202
  column 3
    207.0211 1509.639
    360.92783 1582.9225
    497.07608 1668.4199
    715.5241 1778.593
    1006.15216 1933.0546
    1136.381 2047.051
    1595.1414 2193.618
    2358.7554 2266.9014
    3052.3992 2375.7083
    4227.2686 2567.7627
    5697.999 3004.2505
    7460.303 3430.2625
```

By [redirect output from awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660079/how-to-save-the-output-of-this-awk-command-to-file),

```
#!/bin/awk -f
/^  output/ {
    output=$2
} 

/^  column 2/{
    two=$3
}

/^    [0-9]/{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    print output,two,$i > output
    }
}
```

I've tried to sort it horizontally and output into multiple outputs based on a specific column

`output A.txt` will output all data into A.txt along `column 2` and `column 3` data

It's working but at some point, it just repeated the `output` along with `two` variable, let me know if you have any suggestion.

Actual Result from `A.txt`

```
A.txt 8642 209.98085
A.txt 8642 1513.7103
A.txt 8642 322.45114
A.txt 8642 1574.7799
A.txt 8642 505.41974
A.txt 8642 1656.3765
A.txt 8642 722.01666
A.txt 8642 1819.0581
A.txt 8642 920.3196
A.txt 8642 1994.1241
A.txt 8642 1192.6161
A.txt 8642 2156.9763
A.txt 8642 1497.4697
A.txt 8642 2201.7605
A.txt 8642 2213.728
A.txt 8642 2238.4023
A.txt 8642 3052.3992
A.txt 8642 2375.7083
A.txt 8642 3618.3948
A.txt 8642 2490.941
A.txt 8642 4548.857
A.txt 8642 2630.617
A.txt 8642 5676.56
A.txt 8642 2983.299
A.txt 8642 7460.303
A.txt 8642 3430.2625
A.txt 8642 12284.128
A.txt 8642 4114.6753
A.txt 11202 207.0211
A.txt 11202 1509.639
A.txt 11202 360.92783
A.txt 11202 1582.9225
A.txt 11202 497.07608
A.txt 11202 1668.4199
A.txt 11202 715.5241
A.txt 11202 1778.593
A.txt 11202 1006.15216
A.txt 11202 1933.0546
A.txt 11202 1136.381
A.txt 11202 2047.051
A.txt 11202 1595.1414
A.txt 11202 2193.618
A.txt 11202 2358.7554
A.txt 11202 2266.9014
A.txt 11202 3052.3992
A.txt 11202 2375.7083
A.txt 11202 4227.2686
A.txt 11202 2567.7627
A.txt 11202 5697.999
A.txt 11202 3004.2505
A.txt 11202 7460.303
A.txt 11202 3430.2625
```

Expected output

==> A.txt <==

```
A.txt 8642 209.98085
A.txt 8642 1513.7103
A.txt 8642 322.45114
A.txt 8642 1574.7799
A.txt 8642 505.41974
A.txt 8642 1656.3765
A.txt 8642 722.01666
A.txt 8642 1819.0581
A.txt 8642 920.3196
A.txt 8642 1994.1241
~ and so on ~
```

==> B.txt <==

```
B.txt 11202 207.0211
B.txt 11202 1509.639
B.txt 11202 360.92783
B.txt 11202 1582.9225
B.txt 11202 497.07608
B.txt 11202 1668.4199
B.txt 11202 715.5241
B.txt 11202 1778.593
B.txt 11202 1006.15216
B.txt 11202 1933.0546
~ and so on ~
```

Comment: Everything work fine with the given script & sample. Could you give us the actual result of the script ? Could you try to use `dos2unix` on the input file then run the script ? `dos2unix <input>`

Comment: thanks for the response, i tried as suggested, but it still doesn't work, 
i'll give you actual result

Comment: the post have been edited

Comment: replace `/^  output/` with `/output/` (maybe there is a tab instead of two spaces or special hidden character)

Comment: thanks again but still doesn't work, it outputs the same as attached

Comment: Could you try this command : `awk '/output/{print $0; print $1; print $2}' <input>` and give me the result ? (+ did you try to copy/paste your example from your post to the input file, because I really can't reproduce the issue)

Comment: @user10254032, I second Corentin here even yours is working fine for me.

Comment: @CorentinLimier thanks, I’ll have a look on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fall back to `awk` default field splitting for exact matches instead of regex

```
$ awk '$1=="output"          {f=$2} 
       $1=="column" && $2==2 {n=$3} 
       $1+0==$1              {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print f,n,$i > f}' file
```

this will work regardless you have spaces or tabs.  Last condition is to check whether the field is a number or not, again without regex.